# Rotate the imageview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8.1

I have 3 images, Square, Portrait and Landscape. I would like to rotate the images with the angles 90, 180, 270 and 360 degree. How is it possible using Objective-C ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

CGAffineTransform transform;

```
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.imageView.transform, (M_PI/2));

self.imageView.transform = transform;
```

ImageView will rotate based on current position....

Answer (score 0):

If want just to display the image, add it to a `ImageView` and do this:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

It will rotate the image 90 degree. Hope this helps.. :)